# How to use the pageControl in Collectionview Inside the Tableview?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, swift3, pagecontrol

In my project I used a tableView inside a collectionView and also I used a pageControl. When I swipe the collection view horizontally, I want to switch the pageControl too, but it is not working properly. I used `scrollViewDidScroll` method for switching the `pageControl` as the `collectionView` Swipes. But the problem is, when the tableView scrolls `scrollViewDidScroll` method will again call. So is there any different way or any solution for fix this issue.

Check the below link.

[enter link description here](https://sendvid.com/w3v7ns7h)

**TableView Method**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
{
     return model.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
     cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! FbHomeCell
     cell.btnPushImage.tag = indexPath.row
     cell.collectionView.tag = indexPath.row
     return cell
}
```

**CollectionView Method**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
     return model[collectionView.tag].count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
      collCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! FBHomeCollectionCell    
      collCell.backgroundColor = model[collectionView.tag][indexPath.item]    
      collCell.pageControlSwipe.numberOfPages = Int(collectionView.contentSize.width/collectionView.frame.size.width)                       
      return collCell
 }
```

**Scroll View Delegate Method**

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
{
     let pageWidth = scrollView.frame.width
     collCell.pageControlSwipe.currentPage = Int((scrollView.contentOffset.x + pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth)

     collCell = cell.collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath (item: scrollView.tag, section: 0)) as! FBHomeCollectionCell

 }
```

**Thanks and Appreciate for help..**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can compare which view is scrolling now inside `scrollViewDidScroll`.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == self.collectionView { //Your scrollView outlet
        //Your code here
    }
}
```

**Edit:** First of all you need to implement collectionView's datasource and delegate method with your tableViewCell not with your ViewController also you need to put `pageControlSwipe` in tableViewCell not in the `collectionViewCell`. So it should be look something like this.

```
class FbHomeCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet var pageControlSwipe: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet var btnPushImage: UIButton!

    var colorArray = [UIColor]()              
    var currentPage = 0

    func setCollectionViewWith(colorArray: [UIColor]) {
         self.colorArray = colorArray
         self.collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
         self.collectionView.datasource = self
         self.collectionView.delegate = self
         self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }        

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return colorArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let collCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! FBHomeCollectionCell
        collCell.backgroundColor = self.colorArray[indexPath.item]
        self.pageControlSwipe.numberOfPages = colorArray.count
        return collCell
    }

    //ScrollView delegate method
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
    {
        let pageWidth = scrollView.frame.width
        self.currentPage = Int((scrollView.contentOffset.x + pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth)
        self.pageControlSwipe.currentPage = self.currentPage
    }
}
```

Now call this method in your tableView's datasource method like this.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return model.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! FbHomeCell
        cell.btnPushImage.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.collectionView.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.setCollectionViewWith(colorArray: model[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: yes its work but again when will scroll the collectionview on the next row of tableview then 1st row collectionview show pagecontrol from 0 index.

Comment: @ashmi123 Is your collectionView's cell size is your view size, means device size?

Comment: No wait will show you what exactly want from that u got idea.

Comment: please check the update question I add link and face the above issue.

Comment: @ashmi123 Where you have added collectionView dataSource method?

Comment: In same VC by using extension as "extension FBHomeVC: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource"

Comment: @ashmi123 From your video, It is look like that your collectionView size and its cell size both are same, am i correct?

Comment: Oh thank u...really its work...Just have to change the Currentpage value over there i.e. colorArray.count ...Its work now Thank u so much....really

Comment: @ashmi123 Welcome mate :)

Comment: send me your working sample code  .. i am facing same issue . i m unable to resolve

Comment: @akshay I don't have any demo for it the above code is the working one try it and if you still not make it ask a new question here